# Discontinuous function limit

Tags: limits

Suppose a function is given by:
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0 \\
0               & x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Show that this function is not continuous. Please help - I don't know how to proceed with formally using the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. One way is to use the following  result.

**Proposition.** A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $p\in\mathbb R$ if and only if for every sequence $\{t_n\}$ with $t_n\to p$ we have $f(t_n)\to f(p)$.

Now, let $t_n=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$. Then $t_n\to 0$ but 
$$
f(t_n)=f\left(\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}\right)=\cos\left(2n\pi\right)=1\to 1\neq 0=f(0)
$$
so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the point $x=0$. Consider one of the two sequences which converge to $0$;  $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi }$ or $y_n=\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi }$ for instance, then both sequences go to zero when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ but $f(x_n)=1$ and $f(y_n)=-1$ do not go to zero... thus the function cannot be continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that it is not continous, show that the function is not continous at 0. To do that, think about what hapens to cos(1/x) as x goes to zero, i.e. What happens to cos(x) as x goes to infinity. Does it have zero as a limit? Nah, it oscilates. So because function f is continuous at a point c iff f(c) equals to the limit of f(x) as x goes to c, it is apparent that f is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_n=(2n\pi)^{-1}$ $(n=1,2,3 \ldots)$ and observe that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$. Then compute $f(x_n)$ and ask yourself: is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(0)\,$?

If the answer is "no", then this shows that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.